# Shortcode Contact Form 7 submit doesnt works in admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins, shortcode

Cant get submit work of a contact form 7 shortcode.
Form is correct displayed.
But after submit redirects selft page without notices of successfully submission to database and no mail.

```
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="36650" title="test"]');
```

i tried several things like this

```
if ( function_exists( 'wpcf7_enqueue_scripts' ) ) {
    wpcf7_enqueue_scripts();
}

if ( function_exists( 'wpcf7_enqueue_styles' ) ) {
    wpcf7_enqueue_styles();
}
```

and this

```
 if(in_array('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))){ 
//plugin is activated
}
```

but no success
the only thin what works is in frontpage  copy the html code ofa shortcoded form and insert that in a admin plugin page and as fom action url use the frontpage url. This way it shows the form in admin and at submit it redirects to frontend and ubmit success but its not my really solution.i need it full in backend have someone idea?

Comment: Your english here makes little to no sense so it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. The plugin works perfect out of the box if your surrounding theme is coded properly, CF7 enqueues all its CSS and JS via the wp_head() and wp_footer() WP functions, so for a start there is no need to write any code to manually do this. I would check your console and see if you have any errors to see if anything else is breaking it

Comment: i need the contact form 7 in a admin page in a developed plugin.
in frontend it works without any problems, but in admin page it shows only the form without the success of the submit button.i see no console bugs. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: If you are looking to submit data via the Dashboard, then meta boxes are probably what you want to be looking at - https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/. CF7 is to be used on the front end of a site

Comment: Ahh OK, sounds like you need to enqueue some CF7 scripts to the wp-admin as it loads separately to the front end. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

Comment: Could you just not use this instead? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: @Nick hi have already many customized autofill forms in frontend which generates pdfs and send mails to custome and admin , list them in backend.
i need the admin form in a plugin fuer generating contract pdfs which filling automatically fields from external database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this trick is method for you.

For my solution, I just make cf7 form in the front end page without any footer and header template and embed that with iframe on admin page.

I think this is the only solution to solve this.

Thank you,